# How to disable nested scrolling of viewpager within the nestedscrollview in android activity?

Tags: android

[This is what my nestedscrollview looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuXkH.png)

[This is where my viewpager, along with other views and layouts are placed inside that nestedscrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k15ql.png)

Now issue is that the viewpager, which is swiping fragments of recyclerviews left and right, is not scrolling down along with the nestedscrollview. Activity scrolls only upto the tab layout, as shown in the second picture. Viewpager scrolls nested. Can you **PLEASE** solve this problem?

This is how my main activity's layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_image"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="William Stevenson"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                    android:id="@+id/userName" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Graphic Designer. Freelancer"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                    android:layout_below="@id/userName"
                    android:id="@+id/tagline"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tagline"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="48dp"
                        android:paddingRight="48dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                        android:text="Follow"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:id="@+id/follow"
                        android:background="@drawable/follow_button_flat"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/follow"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:id="@+id/voiceCallMessage"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_none_white_48dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/follow"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:id="@+id/videoCallMessage"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_videocam_white_48dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:rippleColor="#303030"
        app:backgroundTint="#3292D3"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bubble_chart_white_48dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
                android:id="@+id/profileStats"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                            ...


            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:id="@+id/imagesAndVideos"
                android:layout_below="@id/profileStats">

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/frame_layout_corner"
                    android:clickable="false">


                           ...


                </TableLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="800+ Images"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                        android:id="@+id/imagesTag"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                        android:paddingRight="32dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Show All"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/showAll"
                        android:background="@drawable/follow_button_flat"
                        android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
                        android:textSize="14sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <com.gigamole.navigationtabstrip.NavigationTabStrip
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
                app:nts_animation_duration="300"
                app:nts_factor="1.2"
                app:nts_size="16dp"
                app:nts_type="line"
                app:nts_titles="@array/posts_and_friends"
                android:layout_below="@id/imagesAndVideos"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:id="@+id/post_and_friends_nav_strip"/>


            <!--Problem is here-->
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/posts_friends_view_pager"
                android:layout_below="@id/post_and_friends_nav_strip"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is what my both the fragments looks like:

**Fragment 1's layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainPosts"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Fragment 2's layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/friends"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

*Yeah, almost similar.*

**Edit:** I've tried setting android:nestedScrollingEnabled to false in the recyclerview. But It just stops scrolling of the viewpager. Activity can't be scrolled down below the tab layout of the viewpager. Viewpager remains below the phone screen.

**Edit 2:** This is what my main activity looks like:

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView userName, tagline, followers, followersTag, points, pointsTag, following, followingTag, imagesTag;
    ImageView userImage, sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4;
    Button showAllImages;
    Typeface robotoRegular, robotoLight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_profile);

        initActivity();

        ViewPager postsAndFriendsViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.posts_friends_view_pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        ViewPagerAdapterPostsFriends viewPagerAdapterPostsFriends = new ViewPagerAdapterPostsFriends(fragmentManager);
        postsAndFriendsViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapterPostsFriends);

        NavigationTabStrip navigationTabStrip = (NavigationTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.post_and_friends_nav_strip);
        navigationTabStrip.setTabIndex(0);
        navigationTabStrip.setStripColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        navigationTabStrip.setActiveColor(Color.RED);
        navigationTabStrip.setInactiveColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        navigationTabStrip.setViewPager(postsAndFriendsViewPager);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapterPostsFriends extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        ViewPagerAdapterPostsFriends(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position == 0)
                return Posts.init();

            return ProfileFriends.init();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    private void initActivity()
    {
        userImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        sample1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sample1);
        sample2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sample2);
        sample3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sample3);
        sample4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sample4);
        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        imagesTag = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imagesTag);
        tagline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagline);
        points = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.points);
        pointsTag = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointsTag);
        followers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.followers);
        followersTag = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.followersTag);
        following = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.following);
        followingTag = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.followingTag);
        showAllImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showAll);

        robotoLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        robotoRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");


        Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.sample_image).transform(new BrightnessFilterTransformation(this, -0.1f)).into(userImage);

        userName.setTypeface(robotoLight);
        imagesTag.setTypeface(robotoLight);
        tagline.setTypeface(robotoLight);
        points.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
        pointsTag.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
        followers.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
        followersTag.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
        following.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
        followingTag.setTypeface(robotoRegular);
        showAllImages.setTypeface(robotoLight);
    }
}
```

Comment: from my experience, it's not suggested using nested scroll view, because it can confusing the android event handler, it would be more helpful, if you also show your java code

Comment: I've added the java code in the question. So what should I use in place of nestedscrollview?

Comment: if you Change NestedScrollView into ScrollView it help to Scroll slowly